# JLabel that can never equal a certain String

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel

Let's say I have a JLabel called `counter`. How can I make it so that if `counter.getText()` returns  the String `"hello world"`, change the text to `"0"`?

Comment: `if ("hello world".equals(counter.getText())) { counter.setText("0"); }` ... ?

Comment: The key question for me is -- what triggers the check? **When** do you want to check the JLabel's text? Certainly you don't want to poll it intermittently. This suggests that you're looking at using some listener or observer design pattern. Perhaps better then checking the JLabel's text would be to listen for changes to the model's String that is used to set the JLabel's text. If so, a PropertyChangeListener could work well, thereby making the model's String a "bound property".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
JLabel counter = new JLabel("Hello World"); 
String ret;
if(counter.getText().equals("Hello World")){
    ret = counter.getText();
    counter.setText("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JLabel`'s text setter method: [`JLabel#setText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)).

```
if (counter.getText().equals("hello world")) {
    counter.setText("0");
}
```

Something like this would **not** work:

```
String foo = counter.getText();
foo = "bar";
```

This is because you are only changing the reference `foo` points to locally.

Comment: I believe what actually happens when you write foo = "bar" is foo simply points to a different location in memory which is given the data "bar".